# Where can I get official election results for the house for a given year

Tags: united-states, election

I'm looking for official house election results per state per district. Ideally this would be in a format that I can then machine read. I have been looking at Wikipedia for this and it has been woefully inaccurate with missing year etc.

Surely there is some where I can go and get "I want all of the results for STATE for all of the districts broken down by party,candidate, votes"

Has anyone any idea how I can get this?

Comment: This would be hard since the results are likely to be per-Secretary-of-state of each state, as far as "official" go

Comment: If you want to go down the state election pages route, then thegreenpapers has relevant links on its state pages at http://www.thegreenpapers.com/slg/AL.html etc under "election authority" . These will be *very* official, but don't tend to go back past the 90s.

Comment: Hey origimbo, that link is an excellent resource led me to exactly what I want. If you want to put your comment as answer I will mark it as answered. J

Answer (score -1):

[Here is a link to a page on 2016 races from CNN.](http://www.cnn.com/election/results)

Comment: CNN isn't official

Comment: @user4012 Yeah, but on the other hand the op mentions he was originally trying to use Wikipedia, so. . . The CNN results are accurate anyway.